# php cors - can't pass credentials

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to create a site to get data. My real example is: http://hdonline.dongxanhweb.com/. You can test it with method:

Go to this website. Click button Get Video and open Chrome Dev Tool. You can see the error like this:

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response
>   must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. Origin 'http://hdonline.dongxanhweb.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I add in PHP file a code:

```
<?php 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://hdonline.dongxanhweb.com");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: omit");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
?>
```

If I install the extension: [Moesif Origin & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc/related?hl=en) and set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:` from `false` to `true`.
It working. Look like this:

[image]

Have any method to fix my problem? I don't want using this plugin, I want to fix my code.

Comment: If you want to fix this error, you need to be able to modify the headers of the **webpage that you are fetching** and set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the header over there.

Comment: @9KSoft I'm not own on this website. Before I also get data from another website with: `https://cors.io/? + url`. But with this website, it shows different error, I think the problem with my header.

Comment: If you don't own that data, then "No Can Do" :D

Comment: @9KSoft With me, you can be waiting for any users can read my question. :) I believe have the method to do this.

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#wikiArticle on why you are encountering that error.

Comment: Like your comment. Why extension in Chrome: Moesif Origin & CORS Changer is passed?

Comment: @9KSoft Reference link: https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/

Comment: Q: "Why the extension works"? A: Its because, this feature of blocking the cors origin request is implemented at the browser level and its left upto the browsers to block the requests or not. Now, the extension internally must be explicitly telling the browser to not block other origins or maybe it is intercepting the request and adding the respective headers completely transparent to the browser. This is perfectly fine for development purpose but not every user will have that extension installed and if they do, the are defeating the security purpose of COR Security measure provided by browser

Comment: Ok. I know. I want to integrate this plugin to my JS file. Have any method to do this?

Comment: You can implement the fetching server side.

Comment: @9KSoft any suggest> I don't have experience with that.